# Can time be measured in degrees?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, unit-of-measure

As far as I know, minutes and seconds (units of time) are definitely somehow related to the angular conversions we study in high school math (1 degree = 60 minutes, so on and so forth). So why don't we measure time in degrees (or even radians)? Are these minutes in a clock even related to these conversions taught in trigonometry class? And, how are earth's latitudes measured in degrees, I mean latitudes are straight lines and I don't see any angle forming. I'm literally at sixes and sevens right now, please provide me with some insight on this.

Comment: so when we will say time is $\pi/3$ radians . it would actually be 10 minutes. do you mean this?

Comment: I think these terms "degrees, minutes, seconds" go back to use of base sixty in early history, and that they only became used in math for convenience by certain math writers and so are not necessarily related from one use to another.

Comment: @coffeemath according to Wikipedia, "The fact that the terms 'minute' and 'second' also denote units of time derives from Babylonian astronomy, where the corresponding time-related terms denoted the duration of the Sun's apparent motion of one minute or one second of arc, respectively, through the ecliptic. In present terms, the Babylonian degree of time was four minutes long, so the 'minute' of time was four seconds long and the 'second' 1/15 of a second."

Comment: mhm.. makes sense , but the sun's apparent motion was measured in RA and Dec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines of latitude aren't straight lines (even if we interpret "straight line" as "geodesic"); they're circles. The latitude of a point is the the angle made by the pair of rays from the centre of the earth to the point and to a point at the same longitude on the equator.